# Fetching and downloading Maven artifacts programmatically

Tags: java, maven, fetch

I'am looking for a way to search and find some packages (OSGi bundle) from maven central repository, then to download them programmatically (java) or just get the link of them.

Is their any way or library to achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Only maven central? It has a rest api.

Comment: Of course it is possible, what do you think it is that Maven itself does? However, a real answer would be far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the [Aether](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether) project which does exactly what you need. You can check the [AetherStubDownloader from Spring-Cloud-Contract](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/AetherStubDownloader.java) to see the sample usage.

Update:
As you can see in the comment this project has moved to https://maven.apache.org/resolver/

Comment: Do not use Aether anymore it has been moved to https://maven.apache.org/resolver/

Comment: I found Aether, but u need to specify <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version> but i want just made a search based on the name of the jar !

Comment: You don't need to specify the version: just use `+` to resolve the lastest one